# System.out.print removes Matcher class exception

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

So I was using Jsoup to crawl some web pages and this wired issue happens.

With the regex expression of

```
// Sets the prefix for all pages to prevent navigate to unwanted pages.
String prefix = "https://handbook.unimelb.edu.au/%d/subjects";
// Postfix for search page
String searchPostfix = "(\\?page=\\d+)?$";
// Postfix for subject page
String subjectPostfix = "\\/(\\w+)(\\/.+)?$";

String root = String.format(prefix, "2019");
String pattern = root.replace("/", "\\/").replace(".", "\\.");
Pattern reg1 = Pattern.compile("^" + pattern + searchPostfix);
Pattern reg2 = Pattern.compile("^" + pattern + subjectPostfix);
```

With these regex patterns. I ran it with string

```
String s1 = "https://handbook.unimelb.edu.au/2019/subjects/undergraduate";
```

And with a method:

```
private String getSubjectCode(String link) {
    System.out.println(link);
    if (isSubjectPage(link)) {
        Matcher subjectMatcher = subjectPattern.matcher(link);
        System.out.println(link);
        // System.out.println(subjectMatcher.matches());   ## Exception if commented
        System.out.println(subjectMatcher.group(0));
        System.out.println(subjectMatcher.group(1));


        return subjectMatcher.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

What will happen is, if I left that commented line uncommented, the program ran well.

However, if I comment that line

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:645)
    at Page.Pages.getSubjectCode(Pages.java:54)
    at Page.Pages.enqueue(Pages.java:85)
    at Crawler.Crawler.parsePage(Crawler.java:41)
    at Crawler.Crawler.crawl(Crawler.java:51)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

The above Exception will be raised, why will a print line affect how the program is running?

Also, without comment

```
System.out.println(subjectMatcher.matches());   // Exception if commented
// out -> true
```

Comment: It's not the `System.out.println` per se. It's just that you need to call `subjectMatcher.matches()` before `group(...)` — "[IllegalStateException - If no match has yet been attempted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int))"

Comment: Is that so... Then I'm not careful when reading the doc. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `System.out.println` that causes the difference, but a side-effect of calling the method `matches()`.

This is explained in the [JavaDocs of Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

> A matcher is created from a pattern by invoking the pattern's matcher method. Once created, a matcher can be used to perform three different kinds of match operations:
>
> - The `matches` method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.
> - The `lookingAt` method attempts to match the input sequence, starting at the beginning, against the pattern.
> - The `find` method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern.

And

> The explicit state of a matcher is initially undefined; attempting to query any part of it before a successful match will cause an `IllegalStateException` to be thrown. The explicit state of a matcher is recomputed by every match operation.

You need to call either `matches`, `lookingAt` or `find` before you can perform further queries such as `group(0)`.